# Yii2 ArrayDataProvider does not show already paginated data

Tags: php, arrays, yii2

I have an issue with ArrayDataProvider object that Yii2 provides. I have a huge API call that returns more than 7k items (this is a problem because obtaining all items takes a long time). I realized that I can tell the API to paginate for me so I was trying to implement the already paginated data into an ArrayDataProvider but only works in page 1, when I ask for page 2 I see that API returns the next 50 items but in my view the GridView object does not show anything.

An example:

```
$dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'key' => 'id',
        'allModels' => $items,
        'totalCount' => self::GetNumOfItems(),
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['id', 'name', 'email'],
        ],
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 50,
        ],
    ]);
```

I ask for the total amount of items to properly display the paginator. If I ask for page 1 all is working fine but if a change to page 2 or whatever the gridview is showing no items. I suspect that is related with the already paginated data but, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: add `$items` and `totalCount` function too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayDataProvider` paginates through all elements in `$allModels`. So if you have 50 items per page, second page will show models 51-100. If you already have paginated data and `$items` contains only 50 elements from second page, `ArrayDataProvider` will still search for models 51-100, which do not exist, so you get empty page.

In your case you should probably not use `ArrayDataProvider` and write your own data provider which will work like a proxy to API. `ArrayDataProvider` still needs all models to perform sorting or filtering, so either you will fetch all 7k items from API and allow to handle filtering and sorting at `ArrayDataProvider` level, or filtering and sorting should be done at API level and none of existing data provider from framework core will fit your needs. 
You may search for extension with something like `ProxyDataProvider`, but it may be hard to find something that will match your API.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayDataProvider has a "prepareModels" method that forms an array of data. Inside the method, there is an array_slice() function that selects an array slice based on the page number. That's why the gridview doesn't show on other pages any items. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqhjP.png) "prepareModels" method

You can inherit from ArrayDataProvider, override the "prepareModels" method and remove the "array_slice" function.

For example, my [ApiArrayDataProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqOoe.png) and [SearchModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcmTA.png)