# YII2 Set Offset on ArrayDataProvider for Gridview

Tags: php, yii, yii2

if i have fixed 10 data in array, set pagesize to 10, and set totalcount to 50 (5 pages).
The problem i can't show my data (blank) when i am on page 2 which i load only 10 data, so i must load 20 data for display a rows on page 2.

Here my code:
Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new SampleSearch();

    $data = \Sample\Api::get('https://example.com/get-data?page=2');
    /**
     * $data
     * {
     * "totalCount": 50,
     * "data": [
     *     {
     *         "_id": 11,
     *         "name": "Baron"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 12,
     *         "name": "John Doe"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 13,
     *         "name": "Michael Scofield"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 14,
     *         "name": "Wentworth Miller"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 15,
     *         "name": "Valentino Rossi"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 16,
     *         "name": "Marc Marquez"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 17,
     *         "name": "David De Gea"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 18,
     *         "name": "Roronoa Zoro"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 19,
     *         "name": "Mohamed Salah"
     *     },
     *     {
     *         "_id": 20,
     *         "name": "Shadow"
     *     }
     * ]
     * }
     */

    $dataProvider = new ArrayDataProvider([
        'allModels' => $data->data,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 10,
            'page' => isset($_GET['page']) ? ((int)$_GET['page'] - 1) : 0,
        ],
        'sort' => [
            'attributes' => ['_id'],
        ],
        'totalCount' => $data->totalCount,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

How to load page 2 with only 10 data?

Thank in advance
Sorry for my english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 ArrayDataProvider does not show already paginated data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629181/yii2-arraydataprovider-does-not-show-already-paginated-data)

Comment: in your code you have pageseze 1  .. check better

Comment: Oops, sorry i've missed that. Thank you